# JSON parsing unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f3ab10

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to parse a some very basic json data, i doing the exact same whey i always do but i getting the following error:

> -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e7d570 2014-04-30 15:04:33.699 Mensagens 2[7530:60b] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e7d570'

this is the GET.JSON file:

```
{
  "version":"6"
}
```

This is the code in my app where i try to get value of Version:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/app/get.json"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSMutableArray *getVersion = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
getVersion = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSString *currentVersion = [[getVersion objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"version"];

NSLog(@"Version = %@", currentVersion);
```

I just don't see any where things are going wrong.

Comment: Try putting your JSON object data into a `NSDictionary` instead of `NSMutableArray`, and skip the `objectAtIndex:` part, so just `[getVersion objectForKey:@"version"]`

Comment: Read the error. It tells you exactly what the problem is. And the debugger shows you exactly which line is causing the problem. If not, see http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[\_\_NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534504/nscfdictionary-objectatindex-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
NSDictionary *getVersion = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                        options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *currentVersion = [getVersion objectForKey:@"version"];
```

or with new syntax

```
NSString *currentVersion = getVersion[@"version"];
```

because `objectAtIndex` means you are accessing an array but you only have a json object

Comment: JSON object can be an array, in this case it just doesn't appear to be.

Comment: @Stonz2 where is the array ? `{
  "version":"6"
}`

Comment: I know that it's not an array in the asker's example, I'm just pointing out that a JSON object CAN be an array.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer, i will accept your answer asap.

Comment: @Stonz2 `a JSON object CAN be an array` I dont get it? my understanding is `object -> NSDictionary` and `array->NSArray`.

Comment: It's absolutely possible for it to be an array. For example, if your JSON was `[{key:value},{key:value}]` you could read that into an `NSArray` with `JSONObjectWithData`. The expected return value of that method, according to Apple: `A Foundation object from the JSON data` not necessarily just an `NSDictionary`

Comment: To be safe, store the result of `JSONObjectWithData:…` in an `id`, and then check it using `-isKindOfClass:` or `-respondsToSelector:` before calling methods on it. Especially important if you don’t control the source of the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the type you used to declare getVersion, the below method creates NSDictionary or NSArray depending upon the data passed to this method. In your case, it seems that JSON response data is a dictionary, hence even though getVersion is declared (or for that matter even instantiated) to be NSMutableArray object, after execution of below getVersion is a NSDictionary.

```
getVersion = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

As answered by meda, you can use [getVersion objectForKey:@"Version"] to get what you're looking for.