# App crashes with error [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got json response from server as json array.

```
[{
    "id": 514524,
    "firstName": "aa",
    "lastName": "vv",
    "fullName": "aa vv"
}, {
    "id": 51411524,
    "firstName": "qq",
    "lastName": "vv",
    "fullName": "qq vv"
}]
```

But if i am accessing element of that array using `indexPath.row` in `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` like below,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    ProfileViewController *obj = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    obj.isFromScreen = @"Authorized People"; 
    obj.profileArray = [authorizedPeopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES]; 
}
```

I am getting an error as:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aa78d20'
```

Comment: Your response is Dictionary not json array.

Comment: I suspect you are getting the response as Dictionary not as Array. Can you post the response structure that you are getting ?

Comment: it means that you can't ask for element at index in dictionary

Comment: i am getting response as- [
  {
    "id": 514524,
    "firstName": "aa",
    "lastName": "vv",
    "fullName": "aa vv"
  },
  {
    "id": 51411524,
    "firstName": "qq",
    "lastName": "vv",
    "fullName": "qq vv"
  }
]

Comment: Could you provide some code inside didselectrowatindexpath method?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ProfileViewController *obj = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    obj.isFromScreen = @"Authorized People";
    obj.profileArray = [authorizedPeopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}

Here i have set authorizedPeopleArray= authorizedPeopleInfoResponse

authorizedPeopleInfoResponse is response from server

Comment: full method implementation please and update your question with this

Comment: As @ajay_nasa said error happened because you try to get object from `NSDictionary` instance. Make sure that your `authorizedPeopleArray` is a `NSArray` instance. Add breakpoint and check this property

Comment: @SavitaPal How do you parse your JSON into your `authorizedPeopleArray`? The error is in that bit of code. In future, please try to add the relevant bits of code. People here aren't magicians to guess whats going on your end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f3ab10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395143/json-parsing-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x8f3ab10)

Answer (score 1):

Get your `response` like below

```
NSArray *yourArry = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData
    options:kNilOptions error:& error];
```

Get your any value for e.g `firstName` like below in `didselectrowatindexpath`

```
NSString *firstName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
        [[yourArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"firstName"]];
```